# using sed to get the xth, yth, and zth line of a text file

Tags: sed

I know you can use `sed` to get the nth line of a text file as follows:

`sed -n '30p' foo.txt`

will output the 30th line of `foo.txt`

However, suppose I'm interested in the 30th, 39th, 43rd lines of `foo.txt`?  Is there a way to string this together in `sed`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure is...

```
sed -n '30p;39p;43p' foo.txt
```

If they are in a contiguous range, say 39-42 you can do something like this:

```
sed -n '39,42p' foo.txt
```

Comment: In some versions of sed you may have to do `sed -n -e '30p' -e '39p' -e '43p' ...`

Comment: @Ben +1. I know that the first versions of sed did not support `;` as you stated, but other than legacy systems, are there still versions of sed out there that require `-e` ?

Comment: This is great.  Thanks SiegeX and Ben Jackson.

Comment: I think someone mentioned OSX in a comment on a sed question the other day.